# Свой аналог paging library для android

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня уже есть вопрос по этой теме - [Как правильно реализовать бесконечную прокрутку recyclerview на подобии gmail?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923675/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-recyclerview-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B8-gmail).

Там мне посоветовали использовать библиотеку от гугла которая должна была решить мою проблему. Но я не смог ее использовать в своем кастомном recyclerView и поэтому решил сам сделать что-то подобное.

Проблема в том что я не могу придумать как правильно реализовать загрузку данных при достижении начала списка.

Вот слушатель прокрутки:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) 
    {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        int pastVisibleItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (pastVisibleItems + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
            if (next_url != null) {
                getMessages(type, a_token,   Integer.parseInt(Uri.parse(response.body().getNext_url()).getQueryParameter("offset")));
            }
        }

        boolean isRecylerScrollable = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange() > recyclerView.getHeight();
        if(isRecylerScrollable) {
            Log.w("m", "m");
        }

        if (pastVisibleItems >5 && prev_url != null && !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
            //Log.w("m", "m");
            Log.w("m", String.valueOf(isRecyclerScrollable()));
        }
    }
});
```

в этом слушателе идеально работает загрузка данных при достижении нижней точки списка и все работает как нужно и правильно. Возникла проблема в обработке достижения верхней точки.

Сначала я сделал простой слушатель на достижение позиции 0, но после того как данные догрузились после достижения низа списка у меня он срабатывает потому что он достигает верхней точки списка, и это замкнутый круг получается.

Не могу придумать как сделать то что я хочу в нормальном исполнении. Догрузив данные при достижении низа списка я хочу немного прокрутить вниз, а дальше когда вновь достигаю верхней границы списка я посылаю запрос на загрузку предыдущего куска данных.

Я просто не могу представить как доделать то что я уже начал делать. Пробовал через интерфейс в адаптере но тоже не получилось. Грубо говоря у меня при достижении нижней точки списка срабатывает такое условие:

```
pastVisibleItems + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount
```

и по факту мне нужно придумать такое же для достижения верхней точки, но еще и учитывать как-то тот факт что сразу нельзя грузить а после какого-то еще дополнительного условия, что-то типа "можно_загрузить".

Короче я не очень понимаю как правильно сделать.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Долго ковырялся с этой проблемой в итоге вроде получилось то что нужно. Вот моя проверка:

```
if (pastVisibleItems > 1 && pastVisibleItems < 5 && prev_url != null) {
     req = true;
}

if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
   if (prev_url != null) {
      if (req) {
      getMessages(type, a_token, Integer.parseInt(Uri.parse(prev_url).getQueryParameter("offset")));
     }

  }

}
```

в итоге что у меня получается - если мы прокрутили до нижней точки -> послали запрос на подгрузку данных -> дальше при прокручивании списка мы сетим переменную бул в true которая по умолчанию false -> и если мы решаем что нам все-таки нужно вернуться на предыдущую стр с даными мы доползаем до начала списка-> проверяем можем ли мы скролить->проверяем наличие урла для вытаскивания офсета для запроса-> проверяем бул переменную -> если все гуд то шлем запрос и у нас победа.

P.S. вероятнее всего мой ответ будет воспринят как огроменный костыль в программе, и я не против услышать усовершенствования и полезные идеи, потому что сидел долго и не факт что все учел.

### update

пока единственной проблемой с которой я столкнулся, это ошибка о нехватке памяти:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env
```

чисто гипотетически можно в манифесте отключить контроль памяти, но вроде как это не очень хорошо.